# Handlebars adding cdata SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, template, tags, comments

Handlebars keeps adding cdata comment tags  while using SharePoint 2013. I put my handlebars temple in the master page, like on previous sites.

```
<script id="Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">            
        {{#each this}}

            {{#if this.Banner}}
                <div>

                <div class="mainText"> 
                    {{#if this.Section}}  
                        <span class="line"></span>

                        <span class="section-title-sub">{{Section}}</span>
                    {{/if}}
                    <span class="line"></span>

                    <span class="group-title-sub">{{{Section_Name}}}</span>

                </div >
                {{#if this.Logo}}  
                    <div id="logo-right"> 
                        <img class="logo" alt="Div35" src="{{{Logo}}}">
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
</script>
```

This is the first time that when I put this I get the CDATA //]> tags.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different things, I was able to fix it by adding CDATA Comment tags on the Handlebars Template

```
<script id="Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <![CDATA[
        {{#each this}}

            {{#if this.Banner}}
                <div>

                <div class="mainText"> 
                    {{#if this.Section}}  
                        <span class="line"></span>

                        <span class="section-title-sub">{{Section}}</span>
                    {{/if}}
                    <span class="line"></span>

                    <span class="group-title-sub">{{{Section_Name}}}</span>

                </div >
                {{#if this.Logo}}  
                    <div id="logo-right"> 
                        <img class="logo" alt="Div35" src="{{{Logo}}}">
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
                </div>
            {{/if}}
       {{/each}}
       <!-- ]]> -->
</script>
```

Once the comment CDATA Tags were added, everything worked.